# Sitecore Experience Commerce. Create catalog from code

Tags: sitecore-commerce, commerce-engine, commerce-server

Is there a way to create catalog/product from commerce API?
In postman I found example `"Add Catalog"` but it uses "`DoUxActions`action instead of some REST method like `[POST] /Catalogs`

I managed to generate client code from `metadata` (`{{OpsApiHost}}/{{ShopsApi}}/$metadata`) using `Odata Connected Service` in VS
and tried to use generated method for creating new catalog

```
_container.AddToCatalogs(new Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Catalog.Catalog()
            {
                Name = "Test",
                DisplayName = "Test",
                PriceBookName = "Postman_Price_Book",
                PromotionBookName = "Postman_Promotion_Book",
            });
await _container.SaveChangesAsync();
```

but `SaveChangesAsync` throws error

```
"System.NotSupportedException: No action match template 'Catalogs' in 'CatalogsController'"
```

Using postman i was able to get all routes

```
{{OpsApiHost}}/{{OpsApi}}/GetApiRoutes
```

and PUT/POST for Catalogs ins't present.
Is there a way to create catalog/product or do I have to go with `DoUxAction`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to Vlads answer you can also have a look at this plugin, where I implemented a lot of functionality around importing / creating and updating commerce content in general.

https://github.com/Chris1415/Plugin.Sample.Importer

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in next wa in a pipeline block:

```
public class DoActionGenerateCatalog : PipelineBlock<EntityView, EntityView, CommercePipelineExecutionContext>
{
    private readonly CommerceCommander _commerceCommander;

    public DoActionGenerateCatalog(CommerceCommander commerceCommander)
    {
        this._commerceCommander = commerceCommander;
    }

     public override async Task<EntityView> Run(EntityView entityView, CommercePipelineExecutionContext context)
    {
        var createdCatalog = await this._commerceCommander.Command<CreateCatalogCommand>().Process(context.CommerceContext, name, displayName);

       createdCatalog = await this._commerceCommander.Command<GetCatalogCommand>().Process(context.CommerceContext, name);

    }
```